# What is the ethersjs equivalent of `web3.eth.call` in web3js?

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, eth-call, ethers.js

web3.js has [the ability to `call` a transaction and get return data](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-eth.html#call) without sending a transaction:

```
web3.eth.call(callObject [, defaultBlock] [, callback])
```

ethersjs apparently does not have this ability. [These docs](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/v5-beta/api-contract.html?highlight=call#contracts) state:

> These methods cannot return their result to the caller.

**Using etherjs, how can I get the return data of a transaction *without making the actual transaction*?**

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this with an [ethersjs read-only transaction](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-providers.html#contract-execution).

`prototype.call(transaction) => Promise<hex>`